# BizTalk WCF-Custom adapter throws time out in BizTalk server 2016

Tags: sql-server, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I am generating an CUSCAR EDI file from the data available in the SQL db using a WCF-Custom request response port. The volume of data retrived from the db is huge when the response is archived in a physical folder it extends upto 40 MB.

I am frequently getting time out issue, when I request DB for the Data from the BizTalk server 2016. I also increased the receive timeout property under Bindings in the WCF-Custom adapter to 1 hour, still it is failing for almost all the request. Is there any other way of sorting it out.

Comment: Did you setup transactional support on the WCF-SQL send port? If you are only reading data, you probably don't need this and can avoid a transaction time-out.

Answer (score 0):

BizTalk is not made for heavy data transactions, As BizTalK best practices, Data volume should not be more than 1 MB.
 Here in your scenario, data size is exceeded to 40 mb. Normally when any message processed into BizTalk then Biztalk appends a lots of context property so incoming data size will also become 2-10 times heavier in BizTalk message Box.
   There are below options to resolve this issue.
    1. Increase the BizTalk MessageBox size so that BizTalk can handle this 
       heavy data
    2. Reduce the size of response data
    3. use SSIS instead of BizTalk for heavy data transaction